# ¿Cómo generar gráficos de barras dinámicos con chart js?

Tags: chart.js, charts

Estoy usando chart js para mis gráficos, todo bien cuando realizo un gráfico de un label con su propia data, traídos de mi base de datos; quiero saber como poder generar varias data para un solo label, a continuación muestro en ejemplo:

```
<script>
 function Informe_ventas_anuales_sede(anio_desde, anio_hasta){

  $.ajax({
   url: '{{ route('admin.informes.ventas_anuales_sede') }}',
   data: {
     'anio_desde': anio_desde,
     'anio_hasta': anio_hasta,
   },
   success: function(arg){

     // Grafico de ventas anuales

     var ctx = $('#chart_ventas_anuales_sede');
     var myChart = new Chart(ctx,{
       type: 'bar',
       data: {
         labels: ['Magdalena', 'Independencia'],
         datasets: [
          {
            label: 2017,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
            data: [ 127520, 0]
          },
          {
            label: 2018,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(250, 196, 71, 0.5)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
            data: [1332507.47, 0]
          },
          {
            label: 2019,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(229, 250, 71, 0.5)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(229, 250, 71, 1)',
            data: [1276744.20, 79628.19]
          },
          {
            label: 2020,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(71, 226, 250, 0.5)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(229, 250, 71, 1)',
            data: [36502.99, 30136.60]
          }
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        fullWidth: true,
        tooltips:{
          mode: 'index',
          intersect: true,
          callbacks: {
            label: function(tooltipItems, data){
              return full_currency(tooltipItems.yLabel, true);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });

  }
});
}
</script>
```

Ese es el ejemplo en duro, ahora le muestro los datos que traigo en el json

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debería de quedar como muestra la siguiente imagen, pero con los datos dinámicos que traigo desde la base de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3):

He podido realizar este codigo dentro del success:

```
    var labels = [], data = [];

    arg.data.forEach(function(item, i){
      labels.push(item.anio);
      data.push(item.monto);
    });

    var ctx = $('#chart_ventas_anuales_sede');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx,{
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Ventas anuales', 
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)', 
            data: data 
          }
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
```

Y el resultado que obtengo es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]